# app that accesses sim-toolkit in the background

Tags: android, kotlin

Can I build an app that accesses the sim-toolkit options (network-> send money, check balance etc) in the background (as if the user is actually accessing the sim-toolkit application). I want to do this because the standard sim-toolkit is limited and does not provide better search, history, saving options etc. I say `ìn the background` because I have read that direct access to the sim-toolkit is problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SIM toolkit just sends USSD codes and parses the results, which means that one does not need it. And it makes no difference how you access it, while the system is designed to keep this area out of reach. eg. just try calling `*101#` to see the current balance. Or just get some prepaid USIM from a provider, which offers their own API & management app... because else you have the next problem with SMS permissions, which may be required to change eg. the data plan via SMS. Even for such basic functionality ...every provider has another number and other keywords for that.